# "Value too large for defined data type" with "tar" on some devices

Tags: android, busybox

I've got an application on the Market that can send application data from one device to another. To do that I create a .tar archive of the app's data and then send that to the other device over WiFi.

The application is working great on most devices, but so far two users e-mailed me with an error I don't really understand:

```
tar: com.rovio.angrybirdsrio: Value too large for defined data type
```

I'm running the following command on a process with SU permissions:

```
tar --exclude='lib' -xf " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DataSync/Cache/" + dataPackageName + ".tar\n
```

Both users are running BusyBox v1.19.3, but so am I, and it's working fine on my devices. I did some research on the web, but google hasn't been very helpful for a change, so I'm hoping to get an answer here. I'm quite sure the data I'm copying is <4GB, it's more likely somewhere in the <1MB range.

Thank you for your time,
Quint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved by updating/reinstalling Busybox. I'm not sure what the underlying cause is, but at least there's a fix available.